# Azure API App, where to store the plain text file?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-api-apps

Part of the data are stored in Azure SQL, and there are some plain text files need to be accessed by the API App. For example, get a certain line from the plain text, and return it to the client side.

Should I store all the plain text files inside the App_Data folder or store them using the Azure Storage. The total size of the plain text files is around 500MB.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I store all the plain text files inside the App_Data folder or store them using the Azure Storage.

I suggest you store all the plain text files to Azure Storage. To build a stateless API app, we need to store the application data to a shared data center. If you store the text files to App_Data folder and enable [Local Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-local-cache) of your web app. The text files will be save multi copies to each instances of your web app and the data between different instances will not be synced if you don't restart your web app.